# How to display the current screen name inside a Label?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using Kivy Screen Manager and I'm trying to display the current screen's name in a label.  But when I run the app with the following label my app crashes immediately.

```
MyScreenManager:
    LoginScreen:
    MenuScreen:
    SettingsScreen:
    LogoutScreen:

<MenuScreen@Screen>:
    name: 'menu'
    BoxLayout:  
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Header:
    Toolbar:
    BoxLayout:

<Header@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    height: 100
    size_hint_x: 1
    size_hint_y: None
    Label:
        text: 'Dealer App'
        color: 0.212, 0.486, 0.169, 1
        font_size: 48
    Label:
        height: 30
        text_size: self.width*.9, None
        halign: 'right'
        size_hint_y: None
        text: app.root.current_screen
        font_size: 16
        color: 0, 0, 1, 1
```

This label is not used on the first screen but I get the following error when I start the app.

```
...
      89:        halign: 'right'
      90:        size_hint_y: None
 >>   91:        text: app.root.current_screen
      92:        font_size: 16
      93:        color: 0, 0, 1, 1
...
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'
```

I want to use the kv language to add this label.  Is there a problem with line 91 or is it because  the current screen has not been created when this piece of code is run?  If it is the latter how to I make it wait until after a current screen exists?

Comment: Even though you want to use kv, does your code run if write this layout in pure python?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because there is no `app.root` yet. You don't specify where you're loading this kv, but it must be happening before the `App` is built. Basically, you shouldn't try to bind anything via `app.root`.

The way to fix this will depend on your exact kv, but this works for example:

```
ScreenManager:
    Screen:
        name: 'a'
        Label:
            text: root.current
```

If the `ScreenManager` is not the root of your kv rule, then you will need to bind it another way:

```
<MyScreen@Screen>:
    name: 'a'
    Label:
        text: root.manager.current

ScreenManager:
    MyScreen
```

`Screen` instances can access their `ScreenManager` via the `manager` attribute.

Also, you want to use `current`, not `current_screen`. The latter is the actual `Screen` widget, while the former is the string name of the current screen.

Comment: My code is similar to your last example but I have an extra rule which is referenced inside of the Screen instance. In this case it is the BoxLayout "Header".  I wanted to create some components such as header which will be used in several screens.  When I change the label text to  root.manager.current I get this error   AttributeError: 'Header' object has no attribute 'manager'

Comment: I updated the code in the original question to make it clear where label text is in the widget tree.